# Can't prevent a ball from bouncing using Unity 3D physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm using a sphere of size 1. The ball has a RigidBody with mass 0.01. When I rotate the ground, the ball moves because of gravity (I also added a constant force y: -1.5 to the ball). The problem is that the ball bounces when it goes fast. I tried tweaking the physics material (bounciness = 0 and different friction values). How can I prevent the ball from bouncing and achieve a realistic simulation of a metal ball?)

EDIT: I think I've found the problem... the ground is made of boxes (the maze is auto-generated), so it seems that there are "bumps" between them... I've tested it using a big box as a ground, and it's working fine.

This is the problem: https://answers.unity.com/questions/568974/sphere-collider-catching-edges-of-aligned-cubes.html so I think I should use only 1 collider for the ground, and maybe I can use this asset to create the holes: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/csg-82197

[image: ball bouncing]

Comment: Have you tried setting the bounciness of the underlaying terrain to 0 as well? Also can you post the code where you apply the constant force on the -y axis? It might be pushing your ball into the ground, which the rigidbody will then try to counter because it can't go into a solid object

Comment: I'm using the built-in Constant Force script https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConstantForce.html

If I don't apply a negative force on the y axis then the ball flies when I rotate the round

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Mass, and change the Friction in the Physics Material and keep testing it until you got what you want. 
one more tip: on Rigidbody under Constraints, tick up "Freeze Position -- Y-axis" or the up axis in general, this will prevent the ball from going up, maybe this will help

Comment: Increasing the mass didn't help, nor freezing y position (if I do it, then the ground can't push up the ball when rotates)

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine by using the following properties:

[image: Physics Material Properties][image][image]

And i think that `Constant force on Y` is not required or in fact that is causing problem.

Comment: If I remove the constant force, then the ball flies when I rotate the ground. I tried to increase gravity, but it's the same effect as adding a constant force. Here you can see what is happening when I remove the constant force: https://imgur.com/aMAQ6Bi

Comment: Something is wrong with your configuration. Confirm that You have assigned the physics material to both objects(Ball and ground), and set the Rigidbody properties as i have shown in the screenshots. Remember the mass should be realistic for example if ball is 1 kg then ground should be of 2000kg(depending upon the size).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've found the problem (but still no solution), please see my edited question,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient method, but you could try doing a ray trace down and setting the ball's position to the hit position (minus the sphere radius) every frame. It's not pretty but it would do the trick if all else failed.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use constraints in rigid body. If you tick Freeze Y axis position/rotation in constraints, the y movement or bounce will not happen.(Depends if your base level/plane is setup on xz plane).

If that is not an option, then you can try to increase mass and gravity also applying constant AddForce in the upper direction constantly.

You can also add a physics material with decreased bounce and friction like the other mentioned answer.

Comment: I can't freeze y axis because the ball won't move when the ground is rotated.

Comment: Did you try adjusting the bounce and friction by creating and assigning new physx material and increasing mass?

Comment: I tried increasing mass and gravity, and tweaking physics material values. But none of them worked.